# Create list of T2 from list of T1, using T2's constructor that requires T1

Tags: c#, .net, list

If I get a list of `Type1` from method `GetType1List`

```
List<Type1> Type1List = GetType1List();
```

I can then create a list of `Type2` and cycle through the first list using `foreach` to add new `Type2` using its constructor which requires a `Type1` instance:

```
List<Type2> Type2List = new List<Type2>();
foreach(Type1 type1 in Type1List)
{
    Type2List.Add(new Type2(Type1));
}
```

Is there any way I can wrap this up without creating the initial list of `Type1` and without the `foreach` loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using LINQ [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netcore-3.1):

```
List<Type2> Type2List = Type1List
    .Select(type1 => new Type2(type1))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Linq:

```
var TypeList2 = GetType1List().Select(type1 => new Type2(type1)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way seems to be [`List<T>.ConvertAll()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.convertall?view=netframework-4.8) method, without using `System.Linq` reference

```cs
var Type1List = GetType1List();
var Type2List = Type1List.ConvertAll(t1 => new Type2(t1));
```